# VS2013 wndProg Callback method

Tags: c++, methods, visual-studio-2013, wndproc

I want to have a class which creates a window with WinAPI. The wndproc function should be a method of said class. So I found a way of doing so (see code below), but unfortunately it won't compile with VS2013.
This code compiled with VS2010 without errors or warnings.

In my .h file:

```
typedef long(__stdcall* WNDPROC)(void*,unsigned int,unsigned int,long);

class LWindow
{
private:
    //...

    static LRESULT CALLBACK wndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT iMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);


public:
    LWindow(int width, int height, bool framed);
    ~LWindow();

    //...
};
```

In my .cpp file:

```
LWindow::LWindow(int width, int height, bool framed)
{
    //...
    WNDCLASS wc = {0};
    wc.lpfnWndProc = wndProc;
    //...
}
```

The error message is

```
1>l:\opt\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xrefwrap(283): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
```

Comment: Check your #includes and paths. Sometimes they vary between compiler toolset iterations.  BTW, which line is it failing on?

Comment: That line in xrefwrap in inside a variadic template function, impossible to tell how your code got there.  Some sort of C++11 implementation mishap, lots of work was done in VS2013.  Redeclaring WNDPROC was a very bad idea btw.

Answer (score 0):

Well. Now after playing around with this piece of code for nearly an hour and fiddeling with the line `static LRESULT CALLBACK wndProc...`,  because it did not give me a clear line number, I found out that I include some seriously old files which cause a problem.
Thank you, @edtheprogrammerguy, this was the hint I needed!